# Is a bioluminescent analog to hemoglobin possible?

Tags: xenobiology, biochemistry

I'm working on explaining away the existence of a planet whose entire ecosystem is based upon bioluminescent creatures, and I've been wondering if there could be a reason for their blood (or other bodily fluids) to be bioluminescent.

Would it make sense to have a protein that gets to an excited state when combined with oxygen, and then returns to its ground state? If not, would any other explanation be possible?

I'm trying not to make them have a particular bioluminescent organ, but rather to have them emit light when they... explode in a gory mess.

Any pointing towards the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 9):

You might consider adding [**luminol**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminol) to the creatures' bloodstreams. When mixed with an oxidizer (like oxygen) and a catalyst, it becomes luminescent. It turns out that the iron in hemoglobin is a very good catalyst, which is why it's sometimes used at crime scenes to track blood.

The glow dies away quickly, within a minute, meaning that it would have to be constantly replenished. Luminol is not organic, so the organisms couldn't simply produce it. Perhaps it's found easily in the soil or ground on the planet, or maybe it doesn't mix with the blood or an oxidizer until the creature dies. Now, justifying its presence is a bit harder, given that it's not organic. Evolutionarily, it seems to serve no purpose. Again, maybe it just happens to be present in the surrounding environment. The organisms certainly wouldn't need it to survive.

As Joe Bloggs pointed out, the oxygen should be stored in the hemoglobin, which implies that it shouldn't react with the luminol. I don't know if the reactions between the iron in the hemoglobin and the luminol could free up some oxygen; if not, then there won't be a reaction until the luminol (and thus the blood) is exposed to air - just like in the situation described, when the organism dies.

The result of luminol's chemiluminescence? A blue glow:

[image]

<sup>Image courtesy of Wikipedia user The Viewer (David Muelheims) under [the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 2.5 Generic license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/deed.en).</sup>

Comment: Given some of the weird and wonderful chemical compounds even our biosphere is capable of producing I can’t see any reason for an alien one to not produce luminol. A fun question might be what advantage it gives to every creature it’s present in...

Comment: Actually: question: Given that the oxygen in blood is locked up by haemoglobin would this blood only luminesce when exposed to open air?

Comment: @JoeBloggs That's an interesting thought. I don't think I can answer it at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t think there would be anything in principle to prevent haemoglobin being linked to a [luciferin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferin) type molecule to emit light, if there was *an important enough biological reason why that would be beneficial*. But this is problematic because the process would be very energy wasteful.

So any process would have to be important such as mating or life or death escape scenarios. Other forms of bioluminescence might be better if less spectacular.

Exploding does not sound like a good survival strategy unless the species is very interrelated like bees or ants and even then there would be much better ways of creating an explosion than by trying to become a bioluminescent time bomb. Eg the bombardier beetle.
[Bombardier beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle)

Comment: Never underestimate the power of being pretty.

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely a good potential reason for a creature to luminesce on explosion. [Camponotus saundersi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camponotus_saundersi) is an ant that explodes to take out enemies, and the vampire squid ejects a bioluminescent fluid to disorient predators in the dark abyss. It's not a far jump from there imagine an animal that explodes in a bright burst in a dark environment to save its brethren. Even just leaking luminescent blood could be enough of a distraction to let the others escape.

The main problem, as others have noted, is that if the fluorescence is powered by valuable oxygen, that's less oxygen being used for the organism's life processes.

A workaround could be that the hemoglobin's shape is radically changed by being sliced by an enzyme, so that it stops passively carrying and immediately uses the oxygen it's carrying to fluoresce. All you need to do is make the triggering enzyme abundant in the cells/intercellular space outside the veins, or even just under the skin. Then, when the organism was cut/exploded, the enzymes would mix with the blood and react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I’d say **no, there cannot be** an analog between hemoglobin and a light-producing reaction because they use the same molecule (oxygen gas) for different goals. Hemoglobin reacts with oxygen to carry it throughout the body and provide tissues with it for aerobic metabolism. Luciferin reacts with oxygen to destroy it and make it into carbon dioxide. One of the theories for the evolution of bioluminescence is that it was originally created around the time of the great oxidation events as a way for some anaerobic bacteria to get rid of the toxic oxygen.

However, all I think that means is that you can’t use a traditional light-producing molecule like luciferase or luminal or coelenterazine. If you could create a light-producing molecule that *reduced* things instead of *oxidizing* them then there would be a good reason to have them in the bloodstream with hemoglobin and other cells. Even better, if you blast an alien with a bunch of reducing agent in their blood, you’ll get some very dramatic chemical reactions as it’s exposed to the oxygen in the air.

Just as a clarification, light-producing molecules don’t produce light in an “excited state”. They produce light by actively metabolizing, usually oxygen, and each time some oxygen is metabolized there’s a photon or three produced. It’s much like metabolic heat in that way- muscles get warm because they’re actively working, not because they’re in an excited state.